# Can users from one Organizational Unit access computers from another Organizational Unit?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am new to Active Directory and I want to know when I add a user to a organizational unit and add a computer to another organizational unit, will the user from the other organizational unit be able to access the computer on the other organizational unit.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. Your question is a better fit for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: But to answer your question anyway: it depends on what you mean by "access". If you mean "log into", then by default, yes. However, user accounts can have login restrictions (by time or by computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, it will able to access computers from other OU.